# Regular expressions: Finding "negation" of regular expression?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, regular-expressions

Given regular expressions containing *only* `(,),|,*` and characters of an Alphabet A, how can I find the "negation" of a regular expression i.e.:

- `<R1> is a regular expression`
- `<R2> = A*\<R1>`

where `A*` are all the words you can produce with A and `<Ri>` the words accepted by the regular expression `Ri`.

Given R1, how can I find R2? Is there any algorithm to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, this is the standard procedure. However, I've always wondered if there were convenient way to do this without passing through an NFA. I only bring this up because from a practical standpoint converting an NFA to a regular expression can sometimes be a hassle.

Comment: I agree with mhum. I will write a CS test on tuesday. How can I quickly find R2? Is there any "human" way of seeing what to do?

Comment: Straightforward: convert regular expression to a non-deterministic finite state automaton, determinize it, flip the final states (making non-final states final and vice versa), and then convert the resulting automaton to a regular expression. All of these constructions can be found in any good book on automata theory.

A more direct approach is to convert the regular expression to a deterministic finite state automaton directly using [Brzozowski's derivative][1].


  [1]: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=321249

Comment: @Simon why "human"? Is there a Turing test before actual CS test? Just kidding best of luck! :)

Comment: As pointed out by @Moron, this isn't really a research-level question, and hence off-topic here. But perhaps we could take this as a challenge: who can come up with a closely related question that *is* an intriguing research-level problem?

Comment: meta-discussion here: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1015/finding-negation-of-regular-expression-too-basic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As another answer already states, the standard approach is: converting to a DFA, complementing, and converting back to a regular expression takes two exponential steps in the worst case (one for obtaining the equivalent DFA, and one for converting its complement to a regular expression).

This is essentially optimal in the worst case: There are examples of regular expressions of length $n$ such that the shortest regular expression describing complement provably has length at least $2^{2^{c \cdot n}}$, where $c$ is some fixed constant; Such examples are known already for alphabets of size $2$. (Gelade & Neven 2008, and Gruber & Holzer 2008).

- Wouter Gelade, Frank Neven: [Succinctness of the Complement and Intersection of Regular Expressions](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2008/1354/pdf/22011.GeladeWouter.Paper.1354.pdf). STACS 2008: 325-336
- Hermann Gruber, Markus Holzer: [Finite Automata, Digraph Connectivity, and Regular Expression Size.](http://www.hermann-gruber.com/data/icalp08.pdf) ICALP (2) 2008: 39-50

Comment: Very interesting references!

Comment: It is PSPACE-complete to determine whether a regular expression accepts ALL strings. Thus a special case of the original question is PSPACE-complete (determining whether the complement of a regular expression is empty). See Meyer & Stockmeyer [Word Problems Requiring Exponential Time](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804029) (STOC 73) for this and many other interesting decision problems for regular expression variants.